# Render text with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I have a super easy task, not sure how to implement it.

The main controller looks like this:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if render_text.include? "bar"
      render :text => render_text, params: { :bar => true } # http://localhost:3000/main/index?bar=true
    else
      render :text => render_text # http://localhost:3000/main/index
    end
  end

private
  def render_text
    output = Page.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Based on what is output from the database, I would like either to add parameter to url or just render the text without any extra url params.

So preferably the url should look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/main/index?bar=true
```

Comment: output = Page.find(params[:id]) how will this give result with string bar ? what will be result of Page.find(params[:id]), i guess this will assign record found with specified ID to output, and method render_text doesn't return anything also. let me know.

Comment: @Dave, all record of a type Page are returned as a String. Just assume that is a text with some random words

Comment: ok. the method render_text should return the output like this (return output = Page.find(params[:id])) am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, there are numerous issues with your code:

> 1. Why are you passing a param to a url?
> 2. You can't pass a param to a URL without creating a new request (I.E redirecting)

Firstly, why are you passing a param to a URL? Rails has great support for [`sessions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark) which makes it simple & secure to pass data in the backend. I appreciate you may wish to see certain params in the address bar, but I don't understand in this case (more context required)

Secondly, you're using `render :text` as the output. Why?

When Rails processes the inbound request, it will take your user to a specific controller action. So if you have a URL as follows: `domain.com/users/2`, you'll hit the `users#show, id => 2` route. When you process that route in your controller, the output is going to use the data passed in the url (the request is one action)

You are trying to append params to the `url` in the same action. This won't work - you'll have to redirect to a new action with the `bar` param attached:

```
  #app/controllers/main_controller.rb
  def index
      bar = "true" if render_text.include? "bar"
      redirect_to main_index_path(bar: bar)
  end
```